# Create a sequence of new column names

Tags: sas, rename

I have a hundred or so columns which I would like to rename in SAS using the following macro:

```
%macro rename1(oldvarlist, newvarlist);
  %let k=1;
  %let old = %scan(&oldvarlist, &k);
  %let new = %scan(&newvarlist, &k);
     %do %while(("&old" NE "") & ("&new" NE ""));
      rename &old = &new;
      %let k = %eval(&k + 1);
      %let old = %scan(&oldvarlist, &k);
      %let new = %scan(&newvarlist, &k);
  %end;
%mend;
```

The columns are currently named C5, C7, C9, ..., C205 and I would like to rename them AR_0, AR_1, ..., AR100.

With the macro above, how can I put these new names after the comma of the following code without writing each and every one of them?

```
%rename1(C5--C205, # new names here #);
```

Comment: Would there be a connection between the old var names and the new var names? Like C5 would be AR_5 or Would it be that the 1st new var name would be AR_0 regardless of what the old var name was?

Comment: No, the only connection would be that they keep the same order i.e. C5 = AR_0, C7 = AR_1, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a longer solution, but it's fairly dynamic and you easy to see how things work. I'm assuming you'll use the rename statement in proc datasets.  Otherwise you could just be lazy and use arrays to replace then drop the old variables, though that isn't efficient.

```
proc sql;
    create table oldvar as
    select name, varnum
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where upcase(libname)='SASHELP' 
        and upcase(memname)='CLASS'
    order by varnum;
quit;

data rename;
    set oldvar;
    new_var=catx("_", "AR",varnum);
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select catx("=", name, new_var) into :rename_list 
                    separated by " "
    from rename;
quit;

%put rename &rename_list;

proc datasets library=work;
modify my_dataset;
rename &rename_list;
run;quit;
```

Comment: Very useful. I'm just now lacking the final step, I have a table "Rename" which has the columns "name" (current column names of the table Pop09) and "new_var" (required names of the table Pop09) - how do I use this to rename the columns of the table Pop09?

Comment: Add in the proc datasets to do the final "rename".  The library is the library where the data set is stored and my_dataset would be the name of your dataset. Don't forget the quit statement either :) Look up a paper, Proc Datasets Swiss Army Knife for more info on the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This will first find the old columns and rename them to AR_# and create macrovariable varlist that you can use:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table newvar as
    select name
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname="SASHELP" and memname="CLASS"
    order by name;
quit;
data newvar;
  set newvar;
  name=compress("AR_"!!put(_n_,4.));
run;
proc sql noprint;
    select name into :varlist separated by " " 
    from newvar;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, something like this would do the job

```
%macro rename2(oldvarlist, newPrefix);
%let k=1;
%let old = %scan(&oldvarlist, &k);
  %do %while(("&old" NE ""));
    rename &old = &newPrefix.&k.;
    %let k = %eval(&k + 1);
    %let old = %scan(&oldvarlist, &k);
  %end;
%mend;
```